# bash print escaped file contents

Tags: bash, printf, cat

I'm trying to print the file contents with escaped double quotes.

```
# read file contents from ${filename}
# - escape double quotes
# - represent newlines as '\n' 
# print the result
echo "my file contents: \"${out}\""
```

So for example if my file is

```
<empty line>
console.log("hello, world");
<empty line>
```

it should print

```
my file contents: "\nconsole.log(\"hello, world\");\n"
```

I was trying to use printf with %q format specifier, but had problems that it removes the trailing spaces.

Comment: Woah, that is quite an unusual feat. What for? [I could make a C program for it if you wish]

Comment: Show *how* you were trying `printf %q` -- I promise you, it doesn't remove trailing spaces in and of itself. If you were running it in a command substitution (or running `cat` that way), on the other hand...

Comment: Also, that other guy has the right of it -- if you're trying to generate JSON, use a tool built for the job.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy yes, I'm trying to generate JSON

Comment: @PaulStelian I can do it in C as well ;) I wanted a short script to do this

Comment: @CharlesDuffy printf "%q" "$(cat file)" removes the trailing spaces

Comment: @PetrPetrov, that's true because `$(cat file)` itself removes trailing newlines. Instead, try: `IFS= read -r -d '' content <file; printf '%q\n' "$content"`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it gives me $'\nconsole.log("hello, world");\n\n'. Is it a normal practice to remove leading $' and trailing ' ? what about escaping double quotes? do I need to use tr or sed? I thought "%q" would do it

Comment: @PetrPetrov, `printf %q` escapes things *to be parsed by bash*, specifically by the `eval` primitive or any equivalent (called with `bash -c`, passed into the command argument of an `ssh` command line on a system where `/bin/sh` is provided by bash, etc). A string with `$' '` surrounding is a way to provide a literal with nonprintable characters *in bash*. If you want to prepare something to be parsed by a different language, you should be using a different tool for the job; `printf %q` only promises that its output will be usable for bash's `eval`, and for no other purpose.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do only the two literal transforms you've explicitly asked for:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' content <file
content=${content//'"'/'\"'/}
content=${content//$'\n'/'\n'}
echo "file contents: $content"
```

That said, if you're trying to represent arbitrary content as JSON strings, let a fully compliant JSON parser/generator do the heavy lifting:

```
IFS= read -r -d '' content <file
echo "file contents: $(jq -n --arg content "$content" '$content')"
```

...or, even better (to support even files with contents that bash can't store as a string), let `jq` read from the input file directly:

```
echo "file contents: $(jq -Rs . <file)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Command substitutions strip trailing line feeds. You can prevent this by adding a dummy non-linefeed character and then stripping it:

```
printf '\n\nfoo\n\n' > file

contents="$(cat "file"; printf x)"
contents="${contents%x}"

printf "The shell equivalent of the file contents is: %q\n" "$contents"
```

If you are trying to generate JSON, you should instead be using `jq`.

Comment: I've also been known to use `IFS= read -r -d '' contents <file`; assuming no NULs -- and, if it had them, it couldn't be stored in a shell variable anyhow -- that works, albeit with the disadvantage of having a nonzero exit status from `read`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the most reliable way to convert arbitrary multiline text into printf formats would be to use printf, built in to bash.

```
$ nl -ba testfile
     1
     2  console.log("hello, world");
     3
$ s="$(printf '%q' "$(cat testfile; printf x)")"
$ s="${s%x\'}"; s="${s#\$\'}"
$ echo "$s"
\nconsole.log("hello, world");\n\n
```

This has the advantage of handling *all* characters, including CRs and tabs rather than just newlines.

Note the fun command expansion workaround that we employ to avoid stripping the trailing newlines.  (Otherwise, we could just `s="$(printf '%q' "$(<testfile)")"`.)

Note also the parameter expansion we do on the line before `echo`. This is required because of the way bash handles the `%q` format character, returning a format-quoted string rather than just the formatted string.

Comment: Given as `console.log()` is JavaScript source code, it would seem overwhelmingly likely that the OP's desired output is actually a JavaScript string. `printf %q` may work for this *today* (not that I'm asserting this to be true without analysis), but there's no guarantee that it will work for this in the future -- if bash introduces a new extended quoting form tomorrow, `printf %q` would be within specification to *use* that extended quoting form.